# If I heard correctly かけずほど当てにならない, then was it 書けずほど?

Tags: grammar, particle-ほど

I heard the following phrase in response to someone claiming that he had researched documents about some historical figure. The person who had opposing idea commented with:

> かけずほど当てにならない

From the context I guess it must have meant something along "I won't argue with written things" (more literally "If it's not written down, it can't true"), but the use of かけずほど is a mystery for me.

Could it be **書けず**ほど? What would be a grammatical rule behind it? Or could I have misheard it?

Comment: I am only 99% sure of what I am going to say as I did not hear the statement myself.  I think you misheard the "length" of one of the syllables, namely the 「け」.  Try elongating that syllable and you will have a whole new word between the 「か」 and 「ず」.

Comment: @l'électeur Got it, now you only made me wonder about remaining 1% possibility.

Comment: I neither know what ''kakezuhodo'' means nor know an alternative word semantically.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As pointed out by l'électeur in the comments, the person probably said:

> 家系図{かけいず}ほど当てにならないものはない
>   *There is nothing more unreliable than a family tree*